# REACT - Avoid re-rendering page on back browser button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I have a catalog page that shows a lot of products, once the user click one of the product that he possibly selected from the bottom, let say product number 1000, he goes to another page, check stuff etc... AND when he returned to the catalog page using the back button browser everything is rendering again, which makes sense BUT it takes a lot of time to positioning the scroll bar to the previous selected product.

Everything works great when the users select some product at the top of the page, let say product number 4, but when he goes to the bottom, the scenario begins.

Is there any way to cache in REACT this catalog page? in order to avoid the time that it takes to render?

Pagination at the bottom of my catalog page resolve this issue, but I have a LOAD MORE button. I tried with React.memo but it only works when I'm doing things on the current page and not when I landed into the page using the back button.

I'm using react router v5. I could add some codepen with the code here, but first I want to know if this is posible in order to take some direction. I saw pages that even need to render everything once you returned using the back button, looks like static page and the scroll doesnt even move to reach the position of the last product selected. Any light in the dark?

This is my example.

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import Page1 from './Page1';
import Page2 from './Page2';

function App() {
  return (
    <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Link to='/'>home</Link><br />
          <Link to='/page1'>page 1</Link><br />
          <Link to='/page2'>page 2</Link><br />
        </header>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/page1'>
            <Page1 />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/page2'>
            <Page2 />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/'>
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </StrictMode>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => <h1>This is the home</h1>

export default Home;
```

**Page1.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

const Page1 = () => {

  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setCards(json))
      .then(() => scrollToElement());
  }

  const scrollToElement = () => {
    const id = localStorage.getItem('idRef');
    if (id) {
      var access = document.getElementById(id);
      access.scrollIntoView();
    }
  } 

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="grid">
      {cards.map((item) => <Card item={item} key={item.id}/>)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page1;
```

**Page2.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const Page2 = () => <h1>Product selected... now click back browser button</h1>

export default Page2;
```

Comment: Maybe you can try using window.history along with pushState() method to store the scroll of the catalog page in the browsing history and see if that works.

Comment: It should not take much time to restore a scroll position. Is the page doing "other work" when it mounts again? Please [edit] the post to include a relevant [mcve] of the code you are working with and have an issue using.

Comment: Yes @DrewReese it's doing validations and other stuffs but still with the code sample that I've just added to my question I'm getting the same result, which makes sense because it's rendering like 5000 components. So my question is if we have an alternative to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

So there's a couple things working against you in the app.

1. The data is fetched and stored in local state of the component being navigated to. Once the app navigates to another route the data is lost and refetched upon navigating back.
2. There's *a lot* of data to render.

## Possible Suggested Solution

To resolve the issue of state persistence the solution here is to apply the pattern of lifting state up to a common ancestor such that it persists for longer than the routed components being rendered. In the parent `App` component or a custom React Context provider component will suffice.

Example:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const CardDataContext = createContext({
  cards: [],
});

const useCardData = () => useContext(CardDataContext);

const CardDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setCards(json));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <CardDataContext.Provider value={{ cards }}>
      {children}
    </CardDataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Link to="/">home</Link>
        <br />
        <Link to="/page1">page 1</Link>
        <br />
        <Link to="/page2">page 2</Link>
        <br />
      </header>
      <CardDataProvider> // <-- card data provided to all routes
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
          <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </CardDataProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To address the issue of the amount of data that needs to be rendered you can turn to virtualization, or windowing. [`react-window`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) is one that handles this. What this does is that instead of rendering the *entire* array of data to the DOM, potentially thousands of elements, it renders only what fits on the screen plus a little "overscanning" before and after.

Example:

```
import { FixedSizeList as List } from "react-window";
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";

const Page1 = () => {
  const { cards } = useCardData();

  return (
    <div className="grid">
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
          <List
            height={height}
            itemCount={cards.length}
            itemSize={150}
            width={width}
          >
            {({ index, style }) => (
              <div style={style}>
                <Card item={cards[index]} />
              </div>
            )}
          </List>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

One final thing to resolve is scroll restoration to a specific element. `react-window` has the ability to scroll to a specific index. We can update the `CardDataContext` to also hold some scroll state and update the `Page1` component to set and restore a position.

```
const CardDataContext = createContext({
  cards: [],
  scrollIndex: null,
  setScrollIndex: () => {}
});

...

const CardDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  ...
  const [scrollIndex, setScrollIndex] = useState(null);

  ...

  return (
    <CardDataContext.Provider
      value={{
        cards,
        scrollIndex,
        setScrollIndex
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CardDataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const Page1 = () => {
  const { cards, scrollIndex, setScrollIndex } = useCardData();

  const listRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollIndex) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        listRef.current.scrollToItem(scrollIndex, "center");
      });
    }
  }, [scrollIndex]);

  return (
    <div className="grid">
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
          <List
            ref={listRef}
            height={height}
            itemCount={cards.length}
            itemSize={150}
            width={width}
          >
            {({ index, style }) => (
              <div style={style} onClick={() => setScrollIndex(index)}>
                <Card item={cards[index]} />
              </div>
            )}
          </List>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-avoid-re-rendering-page-on-back-browser-button]

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese - That's the solution. However react-window it's generating an extra scroll for the List component (which makes sense) and it seems that there is not any intention to add an extra funcionality that allows us to avoid using react-window list scroll rather than the main viewport scroll.

Comment: @napstercake Yes, virtualization/windowing *can* be a bit of a pain with certain UI layouts.